# Show tag excerpt when editing tags on a question

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, tags, edits

I frequently edit questions by new users in my regular tag [perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl). When it's about the question text I do not look at all the tags before editing. But while I'm at it, I also want to make sure the question does not have inappropriate tags.

However, the tag excerpt is not shown when hovering over the tags in edit mode, even if the pure tag text is already converted to a styled [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag) element. For weird tags that new users set where I don't know if they are relevant, I want to read that excerpt so I can decide if they make sense. But it doesn't show up!

Right now I would just open the question again in a new tab so I can look at the tag excerpts, but that is tedious.

It's also possible to click next to the tag and press <kbd>backspace</kbd> so the auto-complete dialog will show up. That contains the tag excerpt.

[image: before pressing backspace] 
[image: auto-complete with description]

After pressing <kbd>space</kbd> it will convert back to a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag). But again, this is tedious and not the greatest UX.

Can we have those tooltips show up on the [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tags) please?

Comment: +1 - this is a major annoyance for me when editing tags. I have to delete the tag and then retype it to see the excerpt.

Comment: +1; cross-site dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168035/display-tag-excerpt-tooltips-when-editing-a-question

Comment: @pnuts: See dupe, but no, that's just about as annoying. (It's also so non-obvious I was not aware of it until just now. Given how much of an SE power user I am, that's a blatant UX fail.)

Comment: I'm going to mark this (and the duplicate) [meta-tag:status-deferred] — they make a lot of sense to do, but we're not working on them *right now*. Hang in there while we sort this out.

Answer (score -1):

[Userscript](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Scimonster/02cd5e1e901c19ab6ec3/raw/3f0773de252c7eff9b325b11ef3e38edc0e043ef/tagsWhileEditing.user.js) to add that function.